# [UWP][Win2D] How to apply the blur effect over the image with the specified rectangle?

Tags: win2d

I am having a Image and CanvasControl wrapping in Grid panel.For image, i set the horizontal and vertical alignment is left and top and set the size for the image and set the same properties to CanvasControl. Created the BlurEffect and draw the image in the DrawingSession using the DrawImage(blurEffect) but it not draw the image with existing image position. I want to draw the image on the existing image. In my code, the effects applied properly but its image drawing position changed.

My code:

```
 <Grid x:Name="imageGrid">
        <Image x:Name="image" Source="Flower1.jpg" Width="500" Height="400"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
```

Adding the CanvasControl dynamically

```
CanvasControl canv = new CanvasControl();
canv.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
canv.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
```

Draw:

```
  args.DrawingSession.Units = CanvasUnits.Pixels;
args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(blur, new Rect(0, 0, 500, 400), new Rect(0,0,500,400));
```

Please suggest me how to resolve this.